# When is it appropriate to use tensor-based DBs (e.g Marqo) instead of keyword based (e.g Elasticsearch)?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, tensor, marqo

I'm implementing end user search for an e-commerce website. The catalogue contains images, text, prices of different items. LLMs are all the hype at the moment but I'm not sure how well proven the performance is in comparison to keyword based for e-commerce.

I've tried tensor based search and it appears to perform well but its hard to benchmark search against relevance so I'm not sure of putting it into production.

What frameworks are people using to determine when you use tensor/vector based search vs keyword based?